# Remove jquery cloned item on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, responsive-design, clone

Am cloning a item from menu to show on load in a responsive site for that am using jquery function like below

```
if ( $(window).width() <= 699 ) {
$(".navigation li.cart").hide();
$(".navigation li.cart a").clone().insertAfter(".top nav");
} else{
    $(".navigation li.cart").show();
$(".top > a:nth-child(3)").hide() // this is cloned item i want to remove
    }

// ==== On Resize functions
$(window).resize(function() {


if ( $(window).width() <= 699 ) {
    $(".navigation li.cart").hide();
    $(".navigation li.cart a").clone().insertAfter(".top nav");
    } else{
        $(".navigation li.cart").show();
    $(".top > a:nth-child(3)").hide() // this is cloned item i want to remove
        }

});
```

please help me out 
Thanks...

Comment: Any acceptable ideas..?

Answer (score 0):

see if .top > a:nth-child(3) is hide and dont create clone